# extract links from bing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an issue using Python and BeautifulSoup to extract urls from the Bing search engine. I want to extract content within `<div class="b_title">` tags, but when I run this code, the `urls` var is empty:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
payload = { 'q' : 'sport', 'first' : '11' }
headers = { 'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/11.0' }
req = requests.get( 'https://www.bing.com/search', payload, headers=headers )
soup = BeautifulSoup( req.text, 'html.parser' )
urls = soup.find_all('div', class_="b_title")
print urls
```

Comment: Why you make an import of `re`? Why did you add `regex` tag?

Comment: You might need much more libraries, but id doesn't mean that you should specify all of them

Comment: If you want to select links use `select('li.b_algo a')`

Comment: Improved grammar and formatting a bit. Removed irrelevant regex tag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go 2 elements above and select `li` element with its `class` (*it worked for me*) or you can use [SelectorGadets](https://selectorgadget.com/) to grab `CSS` selectors with `select()` or `select_one()` method.

Code and [full example](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Bing-scraping-heading-links-bs4-python-requests#main.py):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

response = requests.get(
    "https://www.bing.com/search?form=QBRE&q=lasagna",
    headers=headers).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

for container in soup.select('.b_algo h2 a'):
  links = container['href']
  print(links)
```

Output:

```
https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/23600/worlds-best-lasagna/
https://www.tasteofhome.com/recipes/best-lasagna/
https://www.foodnetwork.com/topics/lasagna
https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/502/main-dish/pasta/lasagna/
https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/lasagna/
https://www.delish.com/cooking/recipe-ideas/recipes/a51337/classic-lasagna-recipe/
https://www.marthastewart.com/343399/lasagna
https://www.thepioneerwoman.com/food-cooking/recipes/a11728/best-lasagna-recipe/
https://therecipecritic.com/lasagna-recipe/
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [Bing Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/bing-search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

Part of JSON:

```json
"organic_results": [
  {
    "position": 1,
    "title": "World's Best Lasagna | Allrecipes",
    "link": "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/23600/worlds-best-lasagna/",
    "displayed_link": "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/23600",
    "sitelinks": {
      "inline": [
        {
          "title": "Play Video",
          "link": "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/23600/worlds-best-lasagna/"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Code to integrate:

```
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "q": "lasagna",
  "engine": "bing",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for link in results["organic_results"]:
  print(f"Link: {link['link']}")
```

Output:

```
https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/23600/worlds-best-lasagna/
https://www.tasteofhome.com/recipes/best-lasagna/
https://www.foodnetwork.com/topics/lasagna
https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/lasagna/
https://www.delish.com/cooking/recipe-ideas/recipes/a51337/classic-lasagna-recipe/
https://www.marthastewart.com/343399/lasagna
https://www.thepioneerwoman.com/food-cooking/recipes/a11728/best-lasagna-recipe/
```

> Disclaimer I work for SerpApi.